# Injecting module values in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to include additional 'model' objects that are useful in my Angular application. Suppose I have two separate javascript files as shown below. I would like to add a "createStudent" function to my teacher prototype, and have it call the student constructor method. How can teacher.js correctly reference student.js? What is the method for injecting that here?

FYI, I know there are many methods for including rich object models in Angular. I don't want to go the route of using Restangular at the moment for example. I want to keep this extremely simple at the moment, and hopefully increase my understanding of angular modules.

Thanks!!

----------  teacher.js -----------

```js
(function() {

    var teacherConstructor = function() {

        var teacher = {
          student: []
        };
      
        return teacher;

    };


    var module = angular.module("MyApp.models");
    module.value("teacber", teacberConstructor);
}());
```

---------- student.js

```js
(function() {

    var studentConstructor = function(theTeacher) {

        var student = {
          myTeacher: theTeacher
        };
      
        return student;

    };


    var module = angular.module("MyApp.models");
    module.value("student", studentConstructor);
}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution - use `factory`:

```
(function() {
    var module = angular.module("MyApp.models");

    module.factory("teacher", ["student", function(Student) {
        var teacherConstructor = function() {
            ...
            var student = new Student(this);
            ...
        };

        return teacherConstructor;
    }]);
})();
```

Anyway the definition of the teacher "class" must be done inside Angular's definition function, for it to be able to reference the student.

*This however introduces an unecessary closure. I would suggest dropping the outer function, in favor of Angular's native way:*

```
angular.module("MyApp.models").factory("Teacher", ["student", function(Student) {
    var Teacher = function() {
        ...
        var student = new Student(this);
        ...
    };

    return Teacher;
}]);
```

As a sidenote, it is customary for "classes" to start with capital. i.e. `Student`, `Teacher`. And the constructor may as well have the name of the class, thus `teacherConstructor` → `Teacher` in the code above.

Comment: Thanks! That is illuminating. A followup question:
I assume that only one of these .factory() calls can inject the other, otherwise I would have a circular dependency. So I must choose whether Teacher creates new students, or a Student creates it's teacher. Is that right?

And a comment: I have been trying to avoid the use of the 'new' keyword as per Crockford's book "Javascript: The Good Parts", because using a constructor function as opposed to new Teacher() offers a lot of advantages, such as the ability to enforce private vs public functions on an object.

Comment: Hi! About circularity: Yes, you are right - but that would be a problem in any language. You can still have private members with the `new` operator - I may be missing some details of course. But the most productive (IMO) is to pick a style that suits you, so sure, no problem with constructor functions. (Some people would even argue to entirely drop the OO logic and go functional all the way with Javascript :)

Comment: Angular seems to lend itself to functional programming by providing services, which as far as I can see are straight up singletons. I thought about simply flattening my object graph into a bunch of effectively static functions, but couldn't make myself do it.